# javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly Equivalent in Python

Tags: python, spnego, gssapi

Can someone tell me what the equivalent would be if I was using python? In Java I set the following to FALSE to allow for the underlying Kerberos mech to be used instead of SPNEGO.

javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly = false

Comment: Thatparameter does *not* not tell to use Kerberos instead of SPNEGO.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. I know I needed to set that line for my program to work properly. According to information I've found online you set  javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly system property value to false if you want the underlying mechanism to obtain credentials, rather than your application or a wrapper program (such as the Login utility used by some of the tutorials). Shouldn't that be Kerberos?

Comment: Not really, th `false` simply implies that the default module call be called from a `LoginContext`, it does not say what the content of the entry should be. It could be any `LoginModule`.

Comment: i see thanks for the clarification. I will research implementing a login module for the application